# finding connected coordinates using python

Tags: python, coordinates

I am coding using python. I have a list of coordinates and I wanted to figure out if there was a way to have a function return each group of connected coordinates. For example:

```
coordinates = [[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2], [3, 2], [5, 1], [5, 2], [5, 3], [5, 4]]
def get_coordinate_neighbors(coordinates);
   # then you do whatever formula is required #
   return result
get_coordinate_neighbors(coordinates)
# should return [[[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2], [3, 2]], [[5, 1], [5, 2], [5, 3], [5, 4]], ...] #
# please only use one parameter which is the coordinates that I need to find the neighbors of #
```

the length of the list could vary and the coordinates could vary.
"connected" is like how in a chess game, a king can move only one space. The king's coordinate before he moved is connected with the king's coordinate after he moved.

Comment: I suggest you read [how to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Are you defining "connected" as "having the same X coordinate"?  That's not a normal definition of "connected".  `itertools.groupby` can do what you ask.

Comment: it is if the x or y coordinate is 1 coordinate away

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through your coordinates and append every four pairs to a new list.

```
coordinates = [[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4]]
def group(coordinates):
    newcoordinates = []
    for i in range(2):
        newcoordinates.append(coordinates[:4])
        coordinates = coordinates[4:]
    return newcoordinates
print(group(coordinates))
```

Only problem is the range(num) is hardcoded. See if you can figure that one out.